# How to filter array for only exact match in Google Apps Script/Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use Google Apps Script to filter only exact matches.  I've seen similar questions, but I can't seem to apply them to my situation.

On one sheet, I have a table of information which has the item name in column A, its' ingredient in column B, and its' quantity in column C.  Column A contains items named Test and Test 2.  When I filter for Test 2, I get results of both Test and Test 2.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
var costSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Cost');
var ingSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Recipe Ingredient');

// Create list of items to filter from the full list
var rows = costSheet.getLastRow();
var itemList = costSheet.getRange(2, 1, rows - 1).getValues();

// Convert itemList to array to be used in filter
itemList = itemList.join();

// Get full non-filtered data
var fullList = ingSheet.getRange('A2:C514').getValues();

// Apply filter criteria
function checkMatch(item) {
  return itemList.indexOf(item[0]) != -1;
}
filterList = fullList.filter(checkMatch);

// Clear target location, then place filtered data
costSheet.getRange('C2:E514').clearContent();
costSheet.getRange(2, 3, filterList.length, 3).setValues(filterList);
```

I don't have any trouble getting accurate results for multiple items from all three columns, and the only issue I have is when I try to filter an item that begins with the name of another item in the full list (e.g. filtering for Test 2 returns both Test and Test 2, when I want it to just return Test 2).

I am new to working with Google Apps Script/Javascript, hence the 'amateur' coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation:

You are very close!

The issue is related to this line:

```
itemList = itemList.join();
```

Assuming that  `itemList = [["Test 2"],["Test 3"]]` as a result of the `getValues()` method.

If you apply [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) you are converting the above array into the following `string`:

```
Test 1,Test 2
```

Therefore `itemList.indexOf("Test")` will return `0` which means your filter function will evaluate to `true`, but you don't want that since `Test` is not part of your array. You are mistakenly using the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method of `strings` instead of the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method of `arrays`.

Having said that, your goal is to use the the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method of `arrays`. In order to do so, `itemList` needs to be an array and not a string.

To convert a 2D array `[["Test 2"],["Test 3"]]` into a 1D array `[Test 1, Test 2]` you can use [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

### Solution:

**Change:**

```
itemList = itemList.join();
```

**To:**

```
itemList = itemList.flat();
```

### Improved Solution:

Going for the extra mile, you can shorten your code and make it more `JavaScript` modern like that:

```
function shorterFunction(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const costSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Cost');
  const ingSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Recipe Ingredient');
  const itemList = costSheet.getRange(2, 1, costSheet.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat();
  const fullList = ingSheet.getRange('A2:C514').getValues();
  const filterList = fullList.filter(r=>itemList.includes(r[0]))
  costSheet.getRange('C2:E514').clearContent();
  costSheet.getRange(2, 3, filterList.length, 3).setValues(filterList);
}
```

In this solution, I used an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).